# Can you upload two files at once using send_keys in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I'm trying to upload two files into an  element on a webpage – however, after successfully uploading one and trying to upload the other, I get the following error:

> Exception has occurred: StaleElementReferenceException
> Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

So, I was wondering if there was a way to upload two files at the EXACT same time. Although this doesn't work, it would work something like:

```
uploadFiles.send_keys("C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Desktop\\IMAGES\\"+str(image) and "C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Documents\\Image-Line\\FL Studio\\Projects\\finished\\UPLOAD\\"+str(file))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the input tag have multi upload on?

Comment: C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Desktop\\IMAGES\\"+str(image)+ "\n C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Documents\\Image-Line\\FL Studio\\Projects\\finished\\UPLOAD\\"+str(file) try this out

Comment: Check if elements are not changing in the page (e.g. if the element you are clicking to upload is not being refreshed), because if it is you probably just need to find it again in the dom and then send the new file.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan That works! Can you write that in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @ClaudioBatista How would I check if an elements been changed?

Comment: Basically when the DOM changes the elements may change ID so its common for them to not be available if you searched (find_element) before the dom update.
To bypass that just find the element again in the dom before trying to interact with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Desktop\\IMAGES\\"+str(image)+ "\n C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Documents\\Image-Line\\FL Studio\\Projects\\finished\\UPLOAD\\"+str(file)
```

Should send two files to an input tag.

\n seperates each file path.